# How to model this with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table `Users` that has a column called `'r_status'` of type `string`. It's basically the relationship status of that user.

I also have another table Request which needs to have an array of prefered attributes, for example, ['Single', 'Married', 'Divorced']. Later I will need to query Users based on what's inside the preferred attributes array.

I am wondering what's the best way for me to model this? I know that I can store a serial array inside a 'text' type field, but this won't let me query directly, rather I will first have to query Request, then deserialize the array and then query again..

Is there a better way?

I thought about create a new table called 'RelationshipStatus', but this table will only on column, a string 'status'. Is it worth it to create just a table with just 1 column just for the sake of being able to query directly?

Thanks

Comment: Using `serialize` is almost always a quick hack that will cause trouble later; if you're thinking about using `serialize`, think again. An association table is almost always the right choice.

Comment: If you store the allowed values as `"::Single::Married::Divorced::"` then you can do a search with `allowed LIKE '%::<value>::%'`, not so nice but it works

Comment: If you often query base on that info or not, you also should create a new table, that's not a problem. I'm building an online examination app, and I have a table just store name of user's role, with 1 column and 3 row. One new table not make your database bigger, and help your work easy later.

Comment: @KienThanh How do you control the 'role' table? I.e, do you have constant rows, fixed # of rows and you hold reference to them like ENUM?

Comment: in my app, one user has many role, I just need to setup many-to-many association. What do you need control?

Comment: yes, but when you need to create a new user and give them role, for example, 'Student', do you create a new 'Role' object with column 'Student', or do you fetch existing one?

Comment: In my Role table, I have a column called `name`, I have created 3 role, their name are 'admin', 'student', 'teacher'. I set up role base on email. In your case, you just create 3 row with value `'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced'`, and you set up `has_one` association, so when you create new user, you can make a dropdown list on form for user choose one status.